# modify the transnational Emails for different store/store fronts?

Tags: transactional-mail

I know you do this in System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails -> Order ->

But how do I tell the system to pull the correct logo and store name? It currently pulls all this information from the main default store.

Thank you for your order from {{var store.getFrontendName()}}

or

```
> <b>Call Us:</b>  <a href="tel:{{var phone}}">{{var
> store_phone}}</a><br>
```

also here:

> **Email:**  {{var
>   store_email}}

and here:

> {{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}

the logo:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="email-heading">
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload store logo and store name for different store on system->configuration->design